# C++ Runtime string formatting

Tags: c++, stream, string-formatting

Usually I use streams for formatting stuff however in this case ?I don't know the format until runtime.

I want to be able to take something like the following format string:
Hello {0}! Your last login was on {1,date:dd/mm/yy}.
...and feed in the variables "Fire Lancer" and 1247859223, and end up with the following formatted string:
Hello Fire Lancer! Your last login was on 17/07/09.

In other languages I use there is built in support for this kind of thing, eg pythons format string method, however in c++ there doesn't seem to be any such functionality, accept the C print methods which are not very safe.

Also this is for a high performance program, so whatever solution I use needs to parse the format string once and store it (eg mayby a Parse method that returns a FormatString object with a Format(string) method), not reparse the string every time the format method is called...

Comment: Your high-performance program rapidly greets the user?

Comment: @GMan hahahahaha. Im still asking myself that question too

Answer (score 2):

Boost Formatting does that for you:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/format/doc/format.html

Check out this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119098/which-i-o-library-do-you-use-in-your-c-code/119194#119194) for examples of usage:

Answer (score 2):

Your format string looks very much like those used in ICU [MessageFormat](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classMessageFormat.html). Did you consider using it?

Answer (score 0):

[boost::format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) will do the positional arguments portion, but not the date formatting...