# iostream use of << to construct string

Tags: c++, iostream

How can << be used to construct a string ala

```
int iCount;
char szB[128];
sprintf (szB,"%03i", iCount);
```

Comment: You may be interested in Boost.Format: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/format/index.html

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119098/which-i-o-library-do-you-use-in-your-c-code/119194#119194

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
using namespace std;    
stringstream ss;
ss << setw(3) << setfill('0') << iCount;
string szB = ss.str();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int iCount = 42;
    ostringstream buf;
    buf << setw(3) << setfill('0') << iCount;
    string s = buf.str();
    cout << s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can << be used to construct a string ala

This doesn't make any sense.

Use [`std::ostringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostringstream/) in C++ if you want to do the similar thing.

```
 std::ostringstream s;
 int x=<some_value>;
 s<< std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') <<x;
 std::string k=s.str();
```