# Are the C formatted I/O functions (printf, sprintf, etc) more popular than IOStream, and if so, why?

Tags: c++, io, outputstream

I've been looking through a lot of code made by others lately and happened to notice everyone uses "printf" style C functions a lot, but the C++ functions learned in school (cout, specifically) don't seem so popular.

Is this a valid observation, and is there a reason for this?
Convention?

Thanks,

R

Comment: `Everybody` seems a bit of an extreme statement.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119098/which-i-o-library-do-you-use-in-your-c-code/119194#119194

Comment: who are everyone and you shouldn't make such broad assumptions.

Comment: he's completely right tho. it's because iostreams sux so hard it even makes c++ programmers cry, and they're used to crap stuff :)

Comment: I only use `iostreams`, for input, output or formatting. They have their quirks, but at the very least are type safe.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Personally, I use `printf` over the `iostream` stuff (like `cout`) because I think it's clearer.

When you do formatting with `iostream`, you have to `<<` all sorts of weirdness like `setiosflags` and `setf`. I can never remember which namespace all this stuff lives in, let alone what it all does. Even when I do, I'm disappointed with how verbose and unintuitive the code looks.

The formatting options with `printf` may seem illegible at first, but they're concise, clearly documented in a single manual page, and common to a wide range of languages.

Another advanage is that `printf` is stateless: Unlike with `cout`, I don't need to remember which member functions have been called on `printf`, or which byzantine concoction of flags has been `<<`'ed into it. This is a big plus for readability.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the state-vs-stateless distinction. it's really a nice thing when you don't have to worry whether your attempts to output data will step on one-another.

Comment: One thing to point out as well is that you can use printf-style flags with C++ strings using `boost::format`

Answer (score 6):

I think taste is one possible reason. Personally I find this:

```
printf("%8d: %s\n", customer->id, customer->name);
```

more readable than this:

```
std::cout << customer->id << ": " << customer->name << std::endl;
```

There's also the issue with localization. `printf` makes it possible to change the formatting to suit other languages and UI cultures, which becomes a major chore with `iostreams`, unless you use something like the [Boost Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/format/index.html) library.

Comment: Weird answer. Support of locales is actually one point where iostreams are significantly better than printf *and* not really harder to use.

Answer (score 4):

There are several criticisms of the standard stream system -- most notably that it usually is not as performant as C's system, and that they don't allow reordering of the items to be formatted, which can make localization more difficult.

Personally, I use streams for most everything, because they allow me to have a function write to a console, a file, or a string, without having to modify the function.

Comment: You can use streams with printf-style format specifiers with `boost::format`, you know :)

Comment: Passing a `FILE*` as a parameter would be just as easy as passing a `ostream` parameter. Allowing `fprintf` to write to a console, or a file.

Comment: @gwell: Last I checked, I cannot make a FILE* write to a memory buffer.

Comment: @Billy ONeal, look again, these things exist!

Comment: The GNU library supports `fmemopen()`. It is not a standard, but it can exist. See http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_11.html#SEC166

Comment: With streams you can for example write a derivate of `std::ostream` which automatically compresses the data, or an `std::istream` which acts as an SSL decrypter. This is simply more powerful than passing a `FILE*`

Comment: @Gwell: But that requires you to know the size of the output ahead of time. That's (generally speaking) unrealistic.

Answer (score 2):

Where I work, we use `printf`-style formatting.  This is because we used to make heavy use of the MFC `CString` class and its `printf`-style `Format` method.  We've been phasing out MFC, but haven't changed our string-formatting approach.

As for which one is designed better, see [Who architected / designed C++'s IOStreams, and would it still be considered well-designed by today's standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753060/who-architected-designed-cs-iostreams-and-would-it-still-be-considered-well/)

Comment: +1 for the good cross-reference.

Answer (score 0):

The printf and scanf family functions have two major problems: type safety and memory safety.  It's fairly easy to make a mismatch between the specification string and the variable length argument list that follows.  Also, buffer overruns through scanf are a classic security vulnerability.  In short, don't use them.

The C++ streams offer type and memory safety, and also formatting extensibility.  They're much more powerful and generally easier to use than printf and scanf.

Also, as suggested by ShaderOp, Boost's format library provides the same safety, but makes the old C programmers feel more comfortable.

Comment: C++ is low enough level that you can always shoot yourself in the foot, even with streams and "type safety" - for instance, `cout << *(int *)&foo;` On the flip side, any decent C compiler will issue warnings for `printf` format string type mismatches, so I don't think 'safety' is a valid argument for one over the other. On the other hand, C++ streams have at least 2 major disadvantages over `printf` (especially `printf` with XSI localization extensions): ease of translating messages for localization purposes, and statelessness (potentially a big issue with threads).

Comment: The compiler can only verify your format string if it knows what your format string is.  But one of the advantages `printf` has over iostreams is that you can set up the format string at run time.  So type safety certainly seems like a valid argument to me.

Comment: @R any decent C++ compiler will catch the C-style cast and issue a warning as well

Comment: @Dennis: Anyone constructing formatting strings at runtime (with the exception of loading an internationalized version) needs to be shot (for security flaws if nothing else).

Comment: @Billy: Loading an internationalized version is precisely what I was talking about.  The compiler can't help you there.

Comment: @Dennis: GCC can handle that with the format_arg attribute. This attribute means that the function (such as gettext()) modifies a format string in such a way that it takes the same parameters. Furthermore, the gettext tools can check if translated format strings still use the same parameters.

Comment: @Dennis: you'd better have some validation process to check that the internationalized version matches the original version :)

Comment: @jilles: So `printf` is typesafe if you use a specific non-standard library, with its associated pre-processing steps, and your compiler supports specific non-standard extensions? That's not a particularly compelling argument. Don't get me wrong, I prefer C IO to C++ IO for lots of things, and localization is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess printf is more widely used because

- it was in use for quite a few years before C++ compilers and streams showed up
- C is used more than C++
- lots of I/O was done for things like the Windows API, for which printf is a natural fit amongst Open/Read/Write/Close/etc