# Is there a good way to allow a function to write to the console, a file, or a memory buffer without using the IOStream library?

Tags: c++

Comments on [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593135/is-printf-sprintf-etc-more-popular-than-cout-and-why/3593156#3593156) have made me think about how one might implement the same pattern I've been doing with C++ streams. Specifically, I need to be able to have a function which can write to the console, a file, or a string/memory buffer. I don't need most of the formatting features and such that IOStreams provide. Is there some *better* design which would allow this type of redirection idiomatically that's commonly used in other circles?

*for example* - for testing I need to be able to write to a string, but for real program use it's always going to be going to a file or the console.

Comment: @Martin York: I don't need it for any real projects at the moment. Was just curious that since so many seem to like bashing IOStreams, I was wondering if there was a usable replacement for it. Given this is what I use it for 99.9% of the time, I figured I'd ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally untested, but you get the idea.

```
struct stdio_stream {
    enum { invalid_t, file_t, str_t } which;
    union {
        FILE *file_p;
        string *str_p;
    };

    int printf( char *fmt, ... );
    int scanf( char *fmt, ... );

    stdio_stream() : which( invalid_t ), file_p( NULL ) {};

     // etc
};

int stdio_stream::printf( char *fmt, ... ) {
    int ret;
    va_list args;
    va_start( args, fmt );

    if ( which == file_t ) {
        ret = vfprintf( file_p, fmt, args );
    } else if ( which == str_t ) {
        string_p->resize( vsnprintf( NULL, 0, fmt, args )+1, '\0' );
        ret = vsnprintf( &* string_p->begin(), string_p->size(), fmt, args );
    } else throw runtime_error( "uninitialized stream" );

    va_end( args );
    return ret;
}
```

Personally, I think iostream is just great. If I need to go fast, I'll write a fast parser. `printf` still has a lot of room for speed improvement… it's a nice middle ground, I suppose, but still just a compromise.

Comment: I might need an extra `va_start(args); va_end(args);` between the `vsnprintf` calls… not sure.

Comment: Interesting approach. Note that names ending in `_t` are reserved.

Comment: @Jon: I don't have a naming convention for discriminated unions. Oh well. Being inside the class prevents name conflicts: the constants must be accessed as `stdio_stream::file_t` etc.

Comment: @Dennis: They're reserved by POSIX, not the C++ standard proper. @Potatoswatter: Right you are.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may use "CON" filename to write to console as a file, and I believe that's all we can do nice without going over iostream usage complexity.

Comment: That's only going to work on a particular OS, and I can't even imagine which. Reserved filenames went out of style a looong time ago. Macintosh System 4 or 5 did things that way… they changed it as soon as a few more kilobytes were free.

Comment: There are no pretty solutions here :-) This is for M$ ones. For linux there are similar things.

Comment: Yep `/dev/stdout`… moreover there *is* `fprintf` and the `FILE *stdout, *stdin` objects. But then there are memory buffers, too… I suppose `mmap` is another approach ;v) but that's a bit restrictive.