# When virtual inheritance IS a good design?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

EDIT3: Please be sure to clearly understand what I am asking before answering (there are EDIT2 and lots of comments around). There are (or were) many answers which clearly show misunderstanding of the question (I know that's also my fault, sorry for that)

Hi, I've looked over the questions on virtual inheritance (`class B: public virtual A {...}`) in C++, but did not find an answer to my question.

I know that there are some issues with virtual inheritance, but what I'd like to know is in which cases virtual inheritance would be considered a *good* design.

I saw people mentioning interfaces like `IUnknown` or `ISerializable`, and also that `iostream` design is based on virtual inheritance. Would those be good examples of a good use of virtual inheritance, is that just because there is no better alternative, or because virtual inheritance *is* the proper design in this case? Thanks.

EDIT: To clarify, I'm asking about real-life examples, please don't give abstract ones. I know what virtual inheritance is and which inheritance pattern requires it, what I want to know is when it is the good way to do things and not just a consequence of complex inheritance.

EDIT2: In other words, I want to know when the diamond hierarchy (which is the reason for virtual inheritance) **is a good design**

Comment: implementation of iostream classes is ultimate mess, therefore I wouldn't learn from it. btw what are issues with virtual inheritance? Nothing wrong with it, if you are little careful.

Comment: Apart from IOstreams (which is a bad example anyway), I haven't seen virtual inheritance used anywhere else.

Comment: @Charles: I clarified this in my question, but I would say virtual functions, not virtual inheritance if I meant those

Comment: @VJo: a common example is the static_cast from the base to a child problem

Comment: @7vies: Why not say `virtual` base classes as that is unambiguous. There is only one instance of a `virtual` base class in iostreams that I know of Most of the inheritance is non-virtual.

Comment: @VJo: can you defend or reference the "ultimate mess" assertion?

Comment: There is some confusion here but I take it what you want to know is when is a diamond heirarchy good design? rather than technically what is virtual inheritance for

Comment: @jk: exactly! I'll add this into the question, thanks

Comment: @7vies I wouldn't call it a problem. If you don't know what dynamic_cast is for, then get a good book.

Comment: @VJo: Please. It is completely unrelated to my question. And yes I know what dynamic_cast is for and also why people don't always use it, please let's not discuss that!

Comment: I am surprised that an interesting and well-defined question gets all kinds of answers except the ones the OP asks for. perhaps that's the downside of the SO reputation system - people fire off answers without paying enough attention to the question, just to answer early. May I suggest you rephrase the subject and put EDIT2 in bold, so that people notice?

Comment: @davka: Yeah, that was surprising. There are some interesting answers already, though. I will edit the question, indeed

Comment: @Charles iostream was designed in 90s, before the c++ was standardized. By today's standards it is crap. Just open that header, and see what is placed in your hpp/cpp file, and what is instantiated, when you include that header.

Comment: @VJo: I think you may be criticizing your implementation. Are you saying that the _interface_ design is "crap", or just the implementation that you are using?

Comment: @charles See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753060/who-architected-designed-cs-iostreams-and-would-it-still-be-considered-well

Comment: @VJo: What am I supposed to be looking at on that page? I see a combination of some support, some people pointing out _some_ genuine issues and the occasional misinformed criticism. Nothing to justify "ultimate mess" or "crap", but perhaps you can add your own answer to that question explaining your position?

Comment: @charles iostream is probably very tested library and it works fine. operators from it are great. But on that link you can see some problems of that library

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you have an interface hierarchy and a corresponding implementation hierarchy, making the interface base classes virtual bases is necessary.

E.g.

```
struct IBasicInterface
{
    virtual ~IBasicInterface() {}
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

struct IExtendedInterface : virtual IBasicInterface
{
    virtual ~IExtendedInterface() {}
    virtual void g() = 0;
};

// One possible implementation strategy
struct CBasicImpl : virtual IBasicInterface
{
    virtual ~CBasicImpl() {}
    virtual void f();
};

struct CExtendedImpl : virtual IExtendedInterface, CBasicImpl
{
    virtual ~CExtendedImpl() {}
    virtual void g();
};
```

Usually this only makes sense if you have a number of interfaces that extend the basic interface and more than one implementation strategy required in different situations. This way you have a clear interface hierarchy and your implementation hierarchies can use inheritance to avoid the duplication of common implementations. If you're using Visual Studio you get a lot of warning C4250, though.

To prevent accidental slicing it is usually best if the `CBasicImpl` and `CExtendedImpl` classes aren't instantiable but instead have a further level of inheritance providing no extra functionality save a constructor.

Comment: @anatolyg: "class blah inherits method y via dominance". It's just the warning you get when you use the "stacked parallelogram" inheritance model.

Comment: I think it's the silliest warning ever. They might as well print "You are using C++, a complicated language; not only that, you are using multiple inheritance, do you really believe you can master that?"

Answer (score 3):

Virtual inheritance is a good design choice for the case when a class A extends another class B, but B has no virtual member functions other than possibly the destructor. You can think of classes like B as [mixins](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Mixin), where a type hierarchy needs only one base class of the mixin type in order to benefit from it.

One good example is the virtual inheritance that is used with some of the iostream templates in the libstdc++ implementation of the STL. For example, libstdc++ declares template `basic_istream` with:

```
template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits>
class basic_istream : virtual public basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>
```

It uses virtual inheritance to extend `basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>` because istreams should only have one input streambuf, and many operations of an istream should always have the same functionality (notably the `rdbuf` member function to get the one and only input streambuf).

Now imagine that you write a class (`baz_reader`) that extends `std::istream` with a member function to read in objects of type `baz`, and another class (`bat_reader`) that extends `std::istream` with a member function to read in objects of type `bat`. You can have a class that extends both `baz_reader` and `bat_reader`. If virtual inheritance were not used, then the `baz_reader` and `bat_reader` bases would each have their own input streambuf—probably not the intent. You would probably want the `baz_reader` and `bat_reader` bases to both read from the same streambuf. Without virtual inheritance in `std::istream` to extend `std::basic_ios<char>`, you could accomplish that by setting the member readbufs of the `baz_reader` and `bat_reader` bases to the same streambuf object, but then you would have two copies of the pointer to the streambuf when one would suffice.

Comment: The `std::iostream` classes are a horrible example of multiple inheritance.  It doesn't help when the guy who wrote them (Jerry Schwartz) has stated that if he had to do it over again, he would have found a way to avoid using multiple inheritance.

Comment: @Zac: Instantiations of `basic_istream` do not use multiple inheritance.

Comment: mixins or policy based design are useful though. although probably better when you don't also have a heirarchy of policies so MI would be used but not VI

Comment: `basic_istream` does not, nor does `basic_ostream`.  However, the template class derived from both (`iostream`) does.  Hence the reason that `basic_istream` and `basic_ostream` both virtually inherit from `basic_ios`.

Answer (score 1):

Grrr .. Virtual inheritance MUST be used for abstraction subtyping. There is utterly no choice if you are to obey the design principles of OO. Failing to do so prevents other programmers deriving other subtypes.

An abstract example first: you have some base abstraction A. You want to make a subtype B. Please note *subtype* necessarily means another abstraction. If it isn't abstract, it is an implementation not a type.

Now another programmer comes along and wants to make a subtype C of A. Cool.

Finally, yet another programmer comes along and wants something which is both a B and a C. It's also an A of course. In these scenarios virtual inheritance is *mandatory*.

Here's a real world example: from a compiler, modelling data types:

```
struct function { ..
struct int_to_float_type : virtual function { ..

struct cloneable : virtual function { .. 

struct cloneable_int_to_float_type : 
  virtual function, 
  virtual int_to_float_type 
  virtual cloneable 
{ ..

struct function_f : cloneable_int_to_float_type {
```

Here, `function` represents functions, `int_to_float_type` represents a subtype
consisting of functions from int to float. `Cloneable` is a special property
that the function can be cloned. `function_f` is a concrete (non-abstract)
function.

Note that if I did not originally make `function` a virtual base of `int_to_float_type` I could not mixin `cloneable` (and vice versa).

In general, if you follow "strict" OOP style, you always define a lattice of abstractions, and then implementations are derived for them. You separate strictly *subtyping* which only applies to abstractions, and *implementation*.

In Java, this is enforced (interfaces are not classes). In C++ it isn't enforced, and you don't have to follow the pattern, but you should be aware of it, and the larger the team you're working with, or project you're working on, the stronger the reason you will need to depart from it.

Mixin typing requires a lot of housekeeping in C++. In Ocaml, classes and class types are independent and matched by structure (possession of methods or not) so inheritance is always a convenience. This is actually much easier to use than nominal typing. Mixins provide a way to simulate structural typing in a language that only has nominal typing.

Comment: While there are some cases where the design pattern is required, they are very rare.  In most cases, if you have developers saying, "I need this class that is a B-type, and C-type ... both of which are of type A", you are likely making your inheritance tree too deep.  In general, you want your inheritance tree to be as flat as possible to decrease overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual inheritance is not a good or bad thing- it is an implementation detail, just like any other, and it exists to implement code where the same abstractions occur. This is typically the correct thing to do when code must be super-runtime, for example, in COM where some COM objects have to be shared between processes, let alone compilers and suchlike, necessitating the use of IUnknown where normal C++ libraries would simply use `shared_ptr`. As such, in my opinion, normal C++ code should depend on templates and similar and should not require virtual inheritance, but it is totally necessary in some special cases.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're asking for specific examples, I'll suggest intrusive reference counting. It's not that virtual inheritance is good design in this case, but virtual inheritance is the right tool for the job to make it work correctly.

In the early '90s I used a class library that had a `ReferenceCounted` class that other classes would derive from to give it a reference count and a couple of methods for managing the reference count. The inheritance had to be virtual, otherwise if you had multiple bases that each derived non-virtually from `ReferenceCounted`, you'd end up with multiple reference counts. The virtual inheritance ensured you'd have a single reference count for your objects.

Non-intrusive reference counting with `shared_ptr` and others seems to be more popular these days, but intrusive reference counting is still useful when a class passes `this` to other methods. External reference counts are lost in this case. I also like that intrusive reference counting says about a class how the lifecycle of objects of that class are managed.

[I think I'm defending intrusive reference counting because I see it so rarely these days, but I like it.]

Answer (score -3):

Virtual Inheritance is needed when you are **forced** to use multiple inheritance.  There are some problems that cannot be cleanly/easily solved by avoiding multiple inheritance.  In those cases (which are rare), you will need to look at virtual inheritance.  95% of the time, you can (and should) avoid multiple inheritance to save yourself (and those looking at your code after you) many headaches.

As a side note, COM does not force you to use multiple inheritance.  It is possible (and quite common) to create a COM object derived from IUnknown (directly or indirectly) that has a linear inheritance tree.

Comment: not all multiple inheritence requires virtual inheritence, you need to mention diamonds somewhere

Comment: Please don't mention diamonds, it is not what I am asking

Comment: @jk:  I left out the diamond discussion for generalization of the point (which is to avoid multiple inheritance if at all possible).

Comment: @Zac: of course when you are forced to use something, you have to do it. My question is when you are not forced, but would use it anyway because it is the proper solution

Comment: @7vies So you are asking when to use a feature even if it isn't needed? Then the answer is super simple. Never.

Comment: @7vies:  If you are not forced to use multiple inheritance, you will not use it, ever.  I should clarify that a bit:  If you have several interfaces (e.g. IKeyboardListener, IMouseListener, IEventListener) that all have uniquely qualified abstract definitions, it can be effective to have a single class implement all 3.  I do this quite often with my personal game engines.  However, if the base classes are not abstract, you should avoid multiple inheritance if at all possible.  The times multiple inheritance of non-interface classes is useful is few and far between.

Comment: @Zac: this can be an answer to my question, but then it should not be in comments as I'd like to know if the community accepts it or not

Comment: @7vies:  Read "Effective C++" and "More Effective C++" by Scott Meyers.  He has an entire section on the various forms of inheritance and when to use (and not use) them.

Comment: @Zac: Thanks for your suggestion, but in this case I would prefer to know opinion of different people, rather than that of a single person, even as experienced as Scott Meyers

Comment: @7vies:  You are welcome to ask around, but you will get the same answer from any experienced C++ developer.  When guys like Meyers and Sutter (both of whom are on the C++ standards committee) say things like "avoid doing X", people listen ... and for good reason.

Comment: @Zac: The problem with books is that they will often describe the way it is done, but rarely if it is was a good way to do that or not. There are several examples when the standard library stuff was later considered badly designed at some points, and that stands also for the design of the language itself. In general, I prefer to see different opinions with arguments and see how valid they are myself, rather than relying on someone else's ultimate statement. So probably I don't completely share your opinion, but I hope that's ok :)

Comment: @7vies:  Read the Meyers and Sutter books and then get back to me :P  Those books do not just say "do it this way because I said so ..."  They give you reasons why, and show you the pitfalls of not doing it a certain way.  That is why they are mandatory reading for anyone serious about programming C++ professionally.  For more questions regarding this topic:  http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html

Comment: @Zac: that's a different point. Previously you said "When guys like Meyers ... say things like "avoid doing X", people listen", and that's what I answered to. Thanks for the link, it's indeed interesting, but again it's a single person view. Actually, what I am asking for is an example to the 25.3 section there.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be - Most features aren't needed but should still probably be used in some situations: error handling, logging, code formatting, foreach loops, floating-point arithmetic, etc.

Answer (score -3):

[These FAQs](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html) answered all possible questions related to virtual inheritance. Even the answer to your question (if I recognized your questions correctly ;) ) : [FAQ item 25.5](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.5)

Comment: No, it did not for me. It is too abstract and far from real-world, and what it finally says is `So here's what you have to do: T H I N K`. Ok, that's a good advice, but what I am asking for is an example of a design someone thought already and decided to use MI.