# When is virtual inheritance a good idea?

Tags: c++

I'm making a game GUI API where each widget inherits from the Widget class. I was thinking, when others make there own widgets, they might not be fully satisfied with the base class. They might want to add getTheme() for example. Would it be a good idea to make all my widgets virtually inherit from Widget then so that this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "virtual inheritance"?

Comment: @unapersson: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance

Comment: @Mat I'm well aware of virtual base classes. However, C++ has no concept of virtual inheritance, or if it does it is not mentioned in the C++ standard.

Comment: @unapersson: yes it does. Look in section 10 "Derived classes" (i have that in draft n3092 of C++0x, but it's been there way before)

Comment: @Mat Nope, just been through that entire section - no use of the term "virtual inheritance".

Comment: @unapersson: how do you call inheritance that uses `: public virtual Base`?

Comment: @Mat The issue is not what I call it (I would call it derivation from a virtual base), but what the C++ Standard calls, or in this case doesn't call, it.

Comment: @unapersson: fair enough, call it whatever you want, I'll stick with how [Bjarn Stroustrup calls it in The C++ Programming Language, Third Edition](http://cpp-full.info/eBooks_.eBook..Addison.Wesley-The.C...Programming.Language.3rd.Ed..Stroustrup.ISBN.0201889544/pg_0409.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because the user would add their own methods to a child class doesn't mean you need to use virtual inheritance. You would use it if, in your library, you have a single base class with multiple children, and people could inherit from multiple child classes at once (for example mixin rather than substitution).

Answer (score 4):

To resolve a diamond-shaped inheritance problem.  (B and C both inherit from A.  What happens to A's attributes in D that itself inherits from B and C?)

A client of your library could see a RedWidget and a FlyingWidget, and might want to combine them into a RedFlyingWidget.

User would have to specify one of the base classes to be virtual when inheriting.  But that is not responsibility of a library maker.

OOP flows better with single-implementation inheritance, so that's what I'd use throughout a library.

There are also "upside-down inheritance" trees, as described by Alexandrescu's excellent "[Modern C++ Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315)."  They allow clients to pull in more functionality in a form of mix-ins that are called policies.

Programming with policies allows for greater ability to combine functionality, at the expense of syntactical cleanliness.  Think STL implementation, for example.

Comment: it's not the methods you should be concerned about, but the data. If `A` is a pure interface, there is no issue.

Comment: Resolving is _what_ it is. The question is whether it's a good idea.

Comment: @Milo: here's a related discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605556/when-virtual-inheritance-is-a-good-design

Answer (score 1):

> When is virtual inheritance a good idea?

That's a design question.

For your Widgets, I would say Yes, multi-derived classes should have the option to be just 1 Widget.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is a possibility that the users of your library are going to use several classes from your library as a base class (ie derive from them), you have to use virtual inheritance. In other words, it is a good idea to use it in your case.