# Implementing interfaces in C++ with inherited concrete classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I am trying to define interface types in C++ using abstract classes and implement them with concrete classes. The problem I am running into is that I cannot both inherit and interface from another interface and inherit the implementation from a base concrete class.

My goal is to be able to define a hierarchy of interfaces which may inherit from less complex base interfaces. I also want to be able to extend the implementation of interfaces by inheriting from concrete classes (like inheriting from TObjectA in the example below).

This is what I have. The error I am getting is "object of abstract class type "TObjectB" is not allowed". I believe I know why, which is because I didn't implement MethodA() in TObjectB. But I really want is to have the implementation provided by a base class (TObjectA) and still have interface hierarchies (IInterfaceB inherits from IInterfaceA). I also don't want to repeat all the inherited interface methods in my derived concreate classes. How can I do this?

```
class IInterfaceA 
{ 
public:
    virtual void MethodA() = 0; 
}; 

class IInterfaceB : IInterfaceA
{ 
public:
    virtual void MethodB() = 0; 
}; 

class TObjectA : public IInterfaceA 
{ 
public:
    void MethodA() { cout << "Method A"; }  
}; 

class TObjectB : public TObjectA, public IInterfaceB 
{ 
public:
    void MethodB() { cout << "Method B"; } 
}; 

void TestInterfaces()
{
    IInterfaceB* b = new TObjectB(); // error: object of abstract class type "TObjectB" is not allowed
    b->MethodB();
    delete b;
}
```

Comment: You need virtual base classes. E.g. [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605556/when-virtual-inheritance-is-a-good-design/4606206#4606206)

Comment: I've had this exact problem today. In my case, `IInterfaceB` and `TObjectB` were private things in a container while `IInterfaceA` and `TObjectA` were user-supplied.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your class hierarchy, `TObjectB` actually has two `IInterfaceA` base class subobjects:  one inherited through `IInterfaceB` and one inherited through `TObjectA`.  The `MethodA()` from each of them needs to be implemented.

You need to inherit from the interface classes using public *virtual* inheritance, which ensures there is only a single base class subobject of each interface class type:

```
class IInterfaceA 
{ 
public:
    virtual void MethodA() = 0; 
}; 

class IInterfaceB : public virtual IInterfaceA
{ 
public:
    virtual void MethodB() = 0; 
}; 

class TObjectA : public virtual IInterfaceA 
{ 
public:
    void MethodA() { cout << "Method A"; }  
}; 

class TObjectB : public TObjectA, public virtual IInterfaceB 
{ 
public:
    void MethodB() { cout << "Method B"; } 
}; 

void TestInterfaces()
{
    TObjectB b_object;
    IInterfaceB& b = b_object;
    b.MethodB();
}
```

Whether or not such complex class hierarchies are desirable is another matter altogether.

Comment: When I use your code I get the following warning "Warning: 'TObjectB' : inherits 'TObjectA::TObjectA::MethodA' via dominance".

Also when i change the test to use heap allocated objects I get a runtime assertion error and the execution stops:

void TestInterfaces()
{
    IInterfaceB* b = new TObjectB();
    b->MethodB();
    delete b;
}

Comment: Your interface classes must have virtual destructors if you intend to polymorphically delete objects through them.  As for the warning:  avoid complex inheritance hierarchies.

Comment: Note that this might generate some quite horrible virtual pointers and bloat your objects, even though it's not really required.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused by the dreaded diamond inheritance. You've implemented `TObjectA::IInterfaceA::MethodA` but not `IInterfaceB::IInterfaceA::MethodA`.

My recommendation would be to make IIterfaceA and IIterfaceB completely independent. If that's not possible, you can look into virtual inheritance.