# virtual vs non-virtual multiple inheritance in c++

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I am currenlty trying to grasp the concept of multiple virtual/non-virtual inheritance in c++. if I understand correctly if a class B and C inherit virtually from class A, they share a kind of singleton object i.e. they both access same fields of one common object A. Multiple inheritance would create separate A objects for any B and C object.

Taking above into consideration, would anyone be so kind and present it in a simple, practical context? Why mutiple inheritance in the first place and then why virtual/non-virtual?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you read about C++ programming? Multiple or virtual inheritance is tricky, and very often should be avoided. And the issue is for a class D inheriting from both B and C.

Comment: Well i am studying it now, I only had basic introduction. I would definitely be better off if someone could give a simple example on why you would use one or the other. I don't need any complicated/borderline cases. just basic, typical scenarios would be perfect, in one sentence.

Comment: I very rarely have to use multiple inheritance or virtual inheritance. A good rule is to never use it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch "_A good rule is to never use it._" No, a good rule is to use it whenever appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple inheritance is not often [used in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4606034/831725). In most cases it's a mixin of interface / implementation. It's not forbidden, also. The need for (virtual) multiple inheritance comes from design decisions to derive from one general base class:

```
class Window 
{ /* draw, show, hide, background ... */ };

class WindowWithBorder : public virtual Window 
{ /* methods to manipulate / draw border ... */ };

class WindowWithMenu : public virtual Window
{ /* methods to manipulate / draw Menu ... */ };

class MyWindow : public WindowWithBorder, public WindowWithMenu
{ /* now it's your turn ... */ };
```

Those diamond-shaped inheritance graphs must be foreseen by the library implementer. 
Without `virtual` there would be two base `Window` objects, with `virtual` it's only one, but not a singleton, since there can be many windows.

Libraries can often (but not in every case) [avoid](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/inheritance-multiple.html#fqa-25.8) such situations, e.g. by implementing a [composite design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), having a "fat" base class, by implementing abstract interface classes, or by using templates with traits / policies.

I would recommend to read the chapter on class hierarchies in Bjarne Stroustrup's [The C++ Programming language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201700735) (ch. 15 in my 3rd edition, I borrowed the example from).