# Multiple inheritance to solve abstract classes

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

Say I have 4 classes:

```
class I { public: virtual void X() = 0; };
class A : public virtual I { public: virtual void X() { } };
class B : public I {  };
class C : public A, public B { };
```

`I`, `B` and `C` are abstract, where as `A` is not. If I simply add `virtual` to the inheritance of `I` for `B`, then `A::X()` resolves `I::X()` in `C`.

However, I cannot change the source of `B`.

**My question**: Can I get `A::X()` to resolve `I::X` for `C` without being able to change `B`? I have tried declaring `A` and `B` to be virtual to `C` to no avail. I am trying to have no redundant code (e.g. have C declare X() { A::X(); }). Any neat hacks?

Also - there are a few questions very much like this, but I couldn't find any talking about using `virtual` inheritance. Please point to me one if I missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite good: [When virtual inheritance IS a good design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605556/when-virtual-inheritance-is-a-good-design)

The problem here is that in C you have two interfaces I. That is why A::x() satisfies 
its interface I - but it cannot make not abstract interface I from class B. 
For C the only way to have exactly one interface of I - is to change B to derive from I virtually - in this way both I interfaces from A and from B will be merged to one in C. You cannot change B - so the only way is to add this redundant code which you are trying to avoid. I mean define C::X().

Comment: I was hoping I didn't have to define C::X, but that does appear to be the consensus. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is with the vtables. In your current code, you have two of them - one in `A`'s `I` and one in `B`'s `I`. As long as only `A` virtually inherits `I`, you could just as well use regular inheritance and save the overhead. If both virtually inherited `I` you'd have only one instance of `I` in `C`, therefore only one vtable, and `A::X` could indeed cover the pure virual `I::X`.

Given you can't change `B`, the only place you can take care of both vtables is `C`. In my opinion, the way to go is what you mention - just have `C::X` forward the call to `A::X`. There's no code duplication there, and it makes `C` non-abstract:

```
class C : public A, public B {
public:
    virtual void X() { A::X(); }
};
```

As for virtual inheritance, there definitively [have been some here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-inheritance). But you're welcome to ask...

Comment: I very much appreciate your explanation, thank you. Also, the 'smart' link of related questions had some gems as well. I'll be picking PiotrNycz answer - partially because the new guy could use some more reputation :) - and you both gave the answer I needed. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is to compose a `B*` (or smart variant) into `C` instead of inheriting from it, and forward the appropriate methods. You can't do it while maintaining the inheritance, because the compiler won't know which `I`'s inheritance chain to follow.

Comment: interesting idea (point to "neat hack") I didn't mention in the question, but I need to expose C as a B*, so this won't work. But thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: You can actually do this with inheritance from `B`. If you implement `X` in `C` it will serve as final overrider for `X` in both bases.