# C++ show bitmap in hex

Tags: c++, bitmap, hex

I am trying to read a bitmap ("sample.bmp") with fstream in C++. Every char
of the file should be printed as a decimal and hexadecimal number. But the problem is, that at the 60th character or so the decimal numbers become negative. This is the code snippet I use:

//edit: code fixed

```
void bitmap::printHeader(std::string filename){
    std::ifstream bmpFile;
    std::vector<char> line;
    util func;
    bmpFile.open(filename, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
    bmpFile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    std::streampos length = bmpFile.tellg();
    bmpFile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    line.resize(length);
    bmpFile.read(&line[0], length);

    for (int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++){
        std::cout << (int)(UINT8)line[i] << std::endl;
        func.dec2hex((int)(UINT8)line[i]);
    }
    bmpFile.close();
}
```

The first 60 characters are converted right. After that I get numbers from 0 to -255 which are not representing the right chararcter.

Comment: `char` may be signed. Try using `(int)(unsigned char)line[i]` instead of `(int)line[i]`.

Comment: @MikeCAT Or `std::uint8_8` to be more explicit that you are interpreting the value as an integer not a character.

Comment: Use `uint8_t` is you want a generic unsigned byte.

Comment: std::vector<unsigned char> line; -> std::cout << (unsigned int) ...

Comment: (int)(UINT8)line[i]
worked. Thank you.

Comment: Now where is that guy who keeps telling that iostream is not silly but the users are, running into that trap? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753060/who-architected-designed-cs-iostreams-and-would-it-still-be-considered-wel/16615906#16615906