# How do you use printf with a 2D array?

Tags: c++, arrays, printf

I'm trying to create a program with C++ that calculates values for a 2D array and then prints them out in the form of a table. Each nvalue ranges from 1 to 6 decimal places, so I need to give them equal space in the table.
I've tried looking around but I've had trouble understanding it. Can I use `printf` to give equal space to each value in a 2D array? Would I use a for loop to print each value using `printf`?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485963/c-alignment-when-printing-cout) helps!

Comment: If you are using C++, why are you using the C based printf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you have a two dimensional array like :

```
int a[5][4];
```

So if you want to store data and then print, you could try doing it this way:

```
int i,j=0;
cout<< "\nEnter your array values : \n";
for (i=0;i<5;i++){
  for(j=0;j<4;j++){
      cin>>a[i][j];
 }    
}
```

To print :

```
for (i=0;i<5;i++){
  for(j=0;j<4;j++){
      cout<<a[i][j];
 }    
cout<< "\n";
}
```

*Edit: yikes, just re-read your question, you wish to print them in a table?:  yes, you can use printf for equal spaces, just give the new line between the for loops, so that it appears in a table format.*

Comment: And with a close parentheses.

Comment: my mistake... i first wrote using printf, and then i realized the user was asking help in C++, I forgot to edit properly