# Formatting numbers in loop

Tags: c++, numbers, generator, string-formatting

I want to list all numbers from 0000-9999 however I am having trouble holding the zero places.

I tried:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 9999; ++i)
{
cout << i << "\n";
}
```

but I get: 1,2,3,4..ect
How can I make it 0001,0002,0003....0010, etc

Answer (score 11):

See [setfill](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setfill/) for specifying the fill character, and [setw](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setw/) for specifying the minimum width.

Your case would look like:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 9999; ++i)
{
    cout << setfill('0') << setw(4) << i << "\n";
}
```

Comment: @johnsyweb: it just came naturally :)

Comment: Curious, why "\n" and not "endl"?

Comment: @ArunSaha `std::endl()` is a function, and its effect is to return a newline character and flush the stream. You may or may not wish to flush the stream. In most cases we don't really care for things at that level and we pick arbitrarily between the two. But if we don't flush, i.e. if we use `'\n'` rather than `std::endl` then things might be somewhat faster. This is because we write to the stream's buffer rather than the output device. By writing to the buffer we delay writing to the output device. Usually IO devices are expensive to write to compared to writing to a buffer in memory.

Comment: So as a guideline, unless you really want something to appear *right now* (for example, while debugging a crash, because delaying could mean it never appears) it's better to let the buffering amortize the cost of writing to the IO device and use `\n`.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: Thanks for the nice explanation. @Mathieu: Thanks for a simple guideline.

Comment: Another option is the boost format stuff: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119098/which-i-o-library-do-you-use-in-your-c-code/119194#119194

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set some flags:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << setfill('0');
    for(int i = 999; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        cout << setw(4) << i << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ios_base::width()` and `ios::fill()`:

```
cout.width(5);
cout.fill('0');
cout << i << endl;
```

Alternatively, use the IO manipulators:

```
#include<iomanip>

// ...
cout << setw(5) << setfill('0') << i << endl;
```

Comment: Is the top way able to do it without the extra header file?

Answer (score 0):

Though not required, but if you want to know how to do this with C, here is an example:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 9999; i++)
    printf("%04d\n", i);
```

Here, '0' in "%04d" works like `setfill('0')` and '4' works like `setw(4)`.