# should I mix C & C++ style I/O in my C++ program?

Tags: c++, c, iostream, cstdio

This question confuses me lot. Because C++ is a superset of C programmer is free to use C's library functions like printf(), scanf() & many others etc. But I usually like C++ 's Object oriented I/O system & I mostly like to use **cout & cin**. Because iostream is more type safe, less error prone, extensible, flexible & also inheritable. Should I stop using traditional C's I/O functions because of iostream 's advantages or should I modify my program to use ? Which approach is better? Where should I take care when mixing C & C++ I/O. I know that backward compatibility with legacy C programs is necessary, but what should I really do?

Comment: C++ is not a super-set of C. It's a different language that embed also the C.

Comment: Try malloc and delete together and see how that works for you :)

Comment: By default go with the methods that let you express what you are doing most clearly. Typically C++ streams.

Comment: @SergioFormiggini: If it embedded C, then it would be a superset.  It's not a superset because it only "embeds" _most_ of C, but not all of it.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: No, there is no any guarantee that combination malloc() and delete operator will work. It's undefined behavior.

Comment: @meet, correct. Read for example the short and good "A Tour of C++" get a good and pragmatic starting point on what styles to use. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list
Also have a look at the answer by Nibot here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042110/using-scanf-in-c-programs-is-faster-than-using-cin?rq=1

Comment: Sorry guys.  I was picking soemthing I knew was wrong as a counter example to try and prove a point.  Instead, I look like an idiot.  Nothing to see here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ and C streams are synchronized by default, so you can mix them safely.  This behavior is controlled by [std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/sync_with_stdio/).

---

As to whether you *should* do it?  Doesn't matter.  C++ does not have a universal style guide.  Some programmers prefer the C++ iostreams interface, some prefer C's methods, some mix them.

Here are some links that discuss the problem better than I can.

[Should I switch to C++ I/O streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339523/should-i-switch-to-c-i-o-streams)

[The Duct Tape Programmer - Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2009/09/23.html)