# Which stream functions in C++ control the formatting of input and output values of a class?

Tags: c++

Which stream functions in C++ control the formatting of input and output values of a class

Comment: Do you mean the io manipulators? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119098/which-i-o-library-do-you-use-in-your-c-code/119194#119194

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [manipulator functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators).
Also, you can overload the << and >> operators.