# Format a String in C++ with the same convenience as String.format() in Java 5 / 6?

Tags: c++, string, format

Is there a common function available to be able to do `sprintf` type String formatting without having to supply a fixed size buffer, that returns a `string` class instance?

I know about `stringstream` it doesn't do what I want, **I don't want to hard code the position of the tokens in the output statement like it requires.**

I want to be able to define a pattern like `sprintf` lets you, but without the C baggage and in a more idiomatic Object Oriented C++ manner.

Maybe some function that does what `sprintf` does using a `stringstream` and produces a `string` object? Something along the line of the **convenience** of what [String.format()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) does in Java or the equivalent String formatting syntax in Python.

Comment: Can you specifically state what `stringstream` doesn't do that you require?  Combining `stringstream` with the various output specifications from `<iomanip>`, there are very few things you can do with `sprintf` that cannot be replicated.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/119098/14065

Answer (score 10):

[The Boost Format Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/format/doc/format.html):

> The `<boost/format.hpp>` format class provides `printf`-like formatting, in a type-safe manner which allows output of user-defined types.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use Boost.Format or Boost.Locale you can use my simple stringstream wrapper or wrap it even further:

[fakeformat](https://github.com/d-led/fakeformat)

example:

```
REQUIRE( ff::format("{2}ff{1}").with('a').also_with(7).now()=="7ffa" );
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/kYcGJV)